# CSS Slider keeps breaking

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build this slider using only HTML and CSS. I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong that is not making it display like any normal slider. The images are there, but they take up the whole page (and they stack) but it transitions fine:

```css
@keyframes slider {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }

  20% {
    left: 0;
  }

  25% {
    left: -100%;
  }

  45% {
    left: -100%;
  }

  50% {
    left: -200%;
  }

  70%{
    left: -200%;
  }

  75% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  95% {
    left: -300%;
  }

  100% {
    left: -400%;
  }
}
.slider{
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%
}

.slider figure img{
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}

.slider figure{
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  animation: 20s slider infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <figure>
    <img src="images/JonathanJoestar.jpg">
    <img src="images/JosephJoestar.jpg">
    <img src="images/JotaroKujo 3.jpg">
    <img src="images/JosukeHigashikata.jpg">
    <img src="images/GiornoGiovanna.jpg">
    <img src="images/JolyneCujoh.jpg">
    <img src="images/JonnyJoestar.jpg">
    <img src="images/JosukeHigashikata(8).jpg">
  </figure>
</div>
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Some of your `img` are wrapping because of overflow.

Your `figure` has width 500% and each `img` has 20% of it, so each `img` has 100% (20 / 100 * 500%) and it means a `figure` can has only 5 `img`s before it starting wrap their content.

I create [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6nfgm3wu/) based on you code (the wrapping may be a bit weird because of different height). From this fiddle if your change the width to 1000% and 10% for `figure` and `img` (now `figure` can has 10 `img`s) it should works.

If you don't want to deal with this mess. I would suggest you to use Flexbox.

```
.slider figure img {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider figure {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 0;
  animation: 20s slider infinite;
}
```

Full example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6nfgm3wu/1/).